# Is there a way to swap a StackPanel orientation from "Horizontal" to "Vertical" based on container width?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two fixed-size elements currently in a Grid, laid out horizontally. A user has requested to be able to stretch the container vertically and shrink it horizontally, in order to have those two elements appear stacked vertically. I've swapped from a Grid to a StackPanel, but my final hurdle is having the Orientation change. The basic logic would be:

```
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="{Binding (ActualWidth < ActualHeight ? "Vertical" : "Horizontal")}">
```

I apologise if this question is overly vague, I'm still getting used to WPF! Please let me know if there are any additional details that are required to answer this question.

Comment: Changing `Orientation` will change actual size, which in turn will change orientation. You may end up with infinitely flickering control. Look into [custom panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element), because making specialized container is probably the cleanest way.

Comment: Have you considered a `WrapPanel`?

Comment: If you want to stick to `StackPanel`, either write your own `IValueConverter` (use my integer to boolean as an example http://mike.kozlowski.nl/doku.php?id=value_converters#integer_to_boolean_converter_-_converter_with_one_parameter and make it double to orientation) or use QuckConverter (https://github.com/JohannesMoersch/QuickConverter) - QuickConverter won't provide you with design-time values though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `WrapPanel` should give you the behavior that you want. Here is a simple example:

```
<Grid>
    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle
            Width="200"
            Height="200"
            Fill="Red" />
        <Rectangle
            Width="200"
            Height="200"
            Fill="Blue" />
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```